# Could not open the PostgreSQL database in Qt

Tags: database, qt, postgresql

Could not open the PostgreSQL database by Qt.

```
    qDebug()<<QSqlDatabase::drivers()

    QSqlDatabase_Database=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
    QSqlDatabase_Database.setDatabaseName("MYAPP");
    QSqlDatabase_Database.setHostName("localhost");
    QSqlDatabase_Database.setPort(5432);
    QSqlDatabase_Database.setUserName("postgres");
    QSqlDatabase_Database.setPassword("1");

    if(!QSqlDatabase_Database.open())
    {
      qDebug()<<"Could not open the database";
      qDebug()<<QSqlDatabase_Database.lastError().text();
    }
    else
    {
      qDebug()<<Connected;
    }
```

Output:

```
"QPSQL,QPSQL7"
"Could not open the database"
"Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"
```

It is a Windows 7 64 bit PC.

In this PC Qt is not installed.

```
But in the Qt(Qt 5.4) installed PC(Windows 7 32 bit)

Its working perfectly!
```

Comment: On Windows, you have two different drivers (one por 32bits, one for 64bits) May be you forget to install the 32bits on your 64bits Windows.

Comment: where can i get the 64 bit driver?

Comment: in http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/, at the bottom https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/msi/psqlodbc_09_03_0300-1.zip for 32 bits and https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/msi/psqlodbc_09_03_0300-x64-1.zip for 64 bits

Comment: Problem still existing...

Comment: I can connect the database from another PC(Qt installed 32 bit windows) through the same application.

Comment: The application must be deployed with SQL drivers included. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: The above comments about ODBC don't help because the QPSQL driver has nothing to do with ODBC.